# My Aristo Android 7.0 does not have a clock widget

Tags: app-widgets, home-screen, clock

I've followed every link I could find in the last 75 minutes.  Nobody addresses the real issue I am having.  Every one of them tells me how to get to the widgets list, that I should select the clock there and install it to my home screen.

One problem: ***THERE IS NO CLOCK WIDGET TO INSTALL.***  So how can I put a real live ticking clock on my home screen, the way every other phone I have had had one.

Comment: What's the hold-up? Search and install one you like from the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

With a brief search I saw that there are lots and lots of clock widgets in google playstore. Install one from there and then go to the widgets list and at least one will be available.

examples:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.egert.clock&hl=en
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.andreas1724.bigdigitalclock&hl=en

Just search the term 'clock' in google play and you will find many.